# How to make ping website ip using PHP?

Tags: ping

I'm working on a small php script and i'd like to add ping feature to the script. I really don't know how to do it but , i like to have the same result as this : http://www.ipfingerprints.com/ping.php

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the permissions in php, you might be able to

```
<?php system("ping -c 3 localhost"); ?>
```

Be very careful accepting hostnames from web forms - if a user requests that you ping the server "; rm -rf /", you will lose all your data!

Comment: But i want to get the result as table as ipfingerprints

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple

```
<?php

if (!$socket = @fsockopen("YOUR.IP.HERE", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30))
{
  echo "<font color='red'><strong>Offline!</strong></font>";
}
   else 
    {
  echo "<font color='green'><strong>Online!/strong></font>";

  fclose($socket);
}

?>
```

Comment: I want to get the result not to see if website is online or offline

Answer (score 0):

Or use this code " exec('ping -c '.$pingTimes.'.$ipAdress); " at PHP

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have real ping (send ICMP packets) you can take a look at this [Native-PHP ICMP ping implementation](http://code.blitzaffe.com/pages/phpclasses/files/php_icmp_ping_55-16), but I didn't test it.